# Rails - where.not not working properly?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm counting my records on my table `Notifications` by using this query:

`Notifications.where.not(status: 'closed').count`

`Notifications.where.not(status: "closed").count`

`Notifications.where("status != ?", "closed").count`

And I have 1 data that the status is `closed`, so if I run that query, it will give:

```
2.1.0 :024 > Notification.where("status != ?", "closed").count
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `notifications`  WHERE (status != 'closed')
 => 99 (because I have 100 records)
2.1.0 :025 >
```

But, it appears `0` (zero)

How can I fix this.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: SELECT distinct(status) FROM notifications?

Comment: Please tell what type of `status` column?

Comment: Are you sure you are working on same database ? nothing is wrong with your quires.Moreover your console results gives you what you expects so where you get ZERO ?

Comment: I'm already done with this. Thanks for helping. I get some alternative to give the count  that I want.